# React useAsync() not receive a data that return from fetchData()

Tags: reactjs, react-tsx

I want to load data from server before a component is loaded.

```
const fecthData = async () => {
        const apiUrl = "http://localhost:8080/user/natt@gmail.com";
        const requestOptions = {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
        };
       
        const res = await fetch(apiUrl, requestOptions);
        if (!res.ok) throw new Error(res.statusText);
        console.log(res.json());
        return res.json();
    }

    const { data, error, isLoading } = useAsync({ promiseFn: fecthData });
    console.log(data)
    if (isLoading) return <Grid>"Loading..."</Grid>;
    if (error) return <Grid>Something went wrong: {`${error.message}`}</Grid>;
    if (data) return(<Grid>"main code"</Grid>)
```

console.log(res.json()); is return a data from server correctly, but data varible in

```
const { data, error, isLoading } = useAsync({ promiseFn: fecthData });
```

is undefined

I try many other way,ithing useAsync is easy to understand for me (other way is bug too)

Answer (score 0):

now i got solution from my friend, use state with useEffect instead of useAsync

```
const [isLoaded, setIsloaded] = React.useState<boolean | null>(false);
React.useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            await getUser();
            await getGender();
            await getStorage();
            await getGame();
            setIsloaded(true);
        }
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    if (isLoaded) return(//render)
```